# Search both channel fields and related entries fields

Tags: search, relationships, related-entries, reverse-related-entries

Let's say I have two channels, call them "primary" and "secondary". Channel `secondary` is referenced in channel `primary` as a relationship.

Now I want to search the entries of `secondary` based on fields from both channels.

So for example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="secondary" search:field1="foo" search:field2="foo" {related_entries}search:field1="foo"{/related_entries}}
// show entries from channel secondary with "foo" in field1 and field2, and field1 from channel primary
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Obviously that's just pseudo code, but hopefully it illustrates my aim. Also note that I'm using EE 2.5.2, hence the old style tag pair.

I think I read that I would instead need to use reverse related entries, but I'm not sure how that would work. It seems like that would pose the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think Low Search might do what you want: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-relationships